# Data Factory | Copy recursively from multiple subfolders into one folder wit same name

Tags: azure-blob-storage, file-storage, azure-data-factory

Objective: Copy all files from multiple subfolders into one folder with same filenames.
E.g.

```
Source Root Folder
20221110/
  AppID1
    File1.csv
    File2.csv
  /AppID2
     File3.csv
     File4.csv
20221114
   AppID3
     File5.csv
     File6.csv
and so on
Destination Root Folder
    File1.csv
    File2.csv
    File3.csv
    File4.csv
    File5.csv
    File6.csv
```

Approach 1 Azure Data Factory V2 All datasets selected as binary

1. GET METADATA - CHILDITEMS
2. FOR EACH - Childitem
3. COPY ACTIVITY(RECURSIVE : TRUE, COPY BEHAVIOUR: FLATTEN)

This config renames the files with autogenerated names.
If I change the copy behaviour to preserve hierarchy, Both file name and folder structure remains intact.

Approach 2

1. GET METADATA - CHILDITEMS
2. FOR EACH - Childitems
3. Execute PL2 (Pipeline level parameter: @item.name)
4. Get Metadata2 (Parameterised from dataset, invoked at pipeline level)
5. For EACH2- Childitems
6. Copy (Source: FolderName - Pipeline level, File name - ForEach2)

Both approaches not giving the desired output. Any help/Workaround would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If **all of your files are in the same directory level**, you can try the below approach.

First use Get Meta data activity to get all files list and then use copy inside ForEach to copy to a target folder.

**These are my source files with directory structure:**

[image]

**Source dataset:**

**Based on your directory level** use the wildcard placeholder(`*/*`) in the source dataset.

[image]

The above error is only a warning, and we can ignore it while debug.

**Get meta data activity:**

[image]

This will give all the files list inside subfolders.

[image]

Give this array to a ForEach activity and inside ForEach use copy activity.

**Copy activity source:**

[image]

In the above also, the `*/*` should be same as we gave in Get Meta data.

For sink dataset create a dataset parameter and use in the file path of dataset.

[image]

**Copy activity sink:**

[image]

**Files copied to target folder:**

[image]

**If your source files are not in same directory level** then you can try the **recursive approach** mentioned in this [article](https://richardswinbank.net/adf/get_metadata_recursively_in_azure_data_factory) by **@Richard Swinbank**.

Comment: I did the same except for [*/* ](which ideally should have been mentioned on MS documentation), plus I was using binary dataset which was throwing error. This workaround works great. Much appreciated for your efforts.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is in Option 2
Step 3 & 5 :is done as to iterate through the folder and subfolder correct ?

6 . Copy (Source: FolderName - Pipeline level, File name - ForEach2)

I think since in step 6 you already have the filename . On the SINK side , add an dynamic expression and add @Filename and that should do the trick .